# What are some examples of contemporary uses of "arae-a" / 아래아?

Tags: dialects

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hangul#Letters) mentions that 아래아 is

> still used in the Jeju language and sometimes as a substitute for ㅏ a in logos and advertisements

Is this the case, and what are the most obvious examples? How does it change the pronunciation compared to 'ㅏ'?

Comment: This question inspired by https://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/3084/old-korean-alphabets, which I think is a great area for some more questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We do not know how 아래 아 was pronounced when it was made, but yes, in Jeju dialect it is still used. And it is pronounced as [ɒ], or [어]. 아래아's
one usage example is 한/글, a Korean word editor program.

Its logo looks like this.

[image]

아래아 is usually used to make a logo look "archaic". Another example of 아래아 being used in a logo for a product called '참 크래커' is given below.

[image]